# ActionCable is unable to receive data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, actioncable

I am creating a messaging app in Rails 6. Where I have a controller called chatroom, when a registered user enters message, it calls messages_controller.

**The messages_controller.rb looks like this:**

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController
    before_action :require_user

    def create
        message = current_user.messages.build(message_params)

        if message.save
            # redirect_to root_path

            ActionCable.server.broadcast 'chatroom_channel',
                { title: message.body, body: message.body }
        end
    end

    private
    def message_params
        params.require(:message).permit(:body)
    end
end
```

**The chatroom_channel.js under javascript/channels:**

```
import consumer from "./consumer"

consumer.subscriptions.create("ChatroomChannel", {
    connected() {
        // Called when the subscription is ready for use on the server
    },

    disconnected() {
        // Called when the subscription has been terminated by the server
    },

    received(data) {
        // Called when there's incoming data on the websocket for this channel
        window.alert('hi')
        window.console.log('hi')
    }
});
```

But for some reason, I can't see any alert or logging to the browser.

**The standard output from the server after a message is entered:**

```
Started POST "/message" for 127.0.0.1 at 2020-08-27 03:02:08 +0530
Processing by MessagesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"dhkn32ve1N4eIK4Vgg00KcfP/kuEhfhPHGvTLXKlD2c1rtB/9DQTNudSME7sKL4cxe3nS2lQexXhtdLES9mHjg==", "message"=>{"body"=>"Hello, this is a message!!"}, "commit"=>""}
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/application_controller.rb:5:in `current_user'
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  ↳ app/controllers/messages_controller.rb:7:in `create'
  Message Create (1.2ms)  INSERT INTO "messages" ("body", "user_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["body", "Hello, this is a message!!"], ["user_id", 1], ["created_at", "2020-08-26 21:32:08.730711"], ["updated_at", "2020-08-26 21:32:08.730711"]]
  ↳ app/controllers/messages_controller.rb:7:in `create'
   (5.8ms)  commit transaction
  ↳ app/controllers/messages_controller.rb:7:in `create'
[ActionCable] Broadcasting to chatroom_channel: {:title=>"Hello, this is a message!!", :body=>"Hello, this is a message!!"}
No template found for MessagesController#create, rendering head :no_content
Completed 204 No Content in 28ms (ActiveRecord: 7.4ms | Allocations: 4404)


Started GET "/cable" for 127.0.0.1 at 2020-08-27 03:02:15 +0530
Started GET "/cable/" [WebSocket] for 127.0.0.1 at 2020-08-27 03:02:15 +0530
Successfully upgraded to WebSocket (REQUEST_METHOD: GET, HTTP_CONNECTION: keep-alive, Upgrade, HTTP_UPGRADE: websocket)
ChatroomChannel is transmitting the subscription confirmation
```

---

**The `config/cable.yml` file has this content:**

```
development:
  adapter: redis
  url: redis://localhost:6379/1

test:
  adapter: test

production:
  adapter: redis
  url: <%= ENV.fetch("REDIS_URL") { "redis://localhost:6379/1" } %>
  channel_prefix: MessageMe_production
```

I have redis gem in the Gemfile, and also redis server running on 6379. The rails server is running on port 8080.

**routes.rb:**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  mount ActionCable.server, at: '/cable'

  post 'message', to: 'messages#create'

  delete 'logout', to: 'sessions#destroy'
  post 'login', to: 'sessions#create'
  get 'login', to: 'sessions#new'

  get 'chatroom/index'
  get 'chatroom', to: 'chatroom#index'
  get 'chatroom/help'
  root to: 'chatroom#index'
end
```

---

If I insert a `console.log('Hello!')` inside the `connected()` function I can see that in the browser.

Yes, the data is getting saved, and if I put some code in `if message.save` that is executed. Yet, ActionCable's receive() not working.

Am I missing something?

Comment: The channel name on the ruby side is given as 'chatroom_channel' but the channel on the JS side is 'ChatroomChannel'. They should be the same.

Comment: Hello, the Ruby file is called chatroom_channel.rb, and the JS file is called chatroom_channel.js. It was created by the command `rails g channel chatroom`. I just modified the received function in the JS file, and cable.yml file to insert redis, because async wasn't working as well. Changing the names didn't work either. If I am wrong, can you specify exactly what to change?

Comment: That was a ridiculous mistake. I forgot to add `stream_from 'chatroom_channel'` in the chatroom_channel.rb file. It's working perfectly :)